# Correct image path to delete from storage laravel 8

Tags: file-upload, path, storage, laravel-8

I try to delete the old profilepicture in storage file but it is not working.
below is my screenshot of my files

[image]

and this is my code in update profile controller.

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('profilepicture')) {

        Storage::delete('/storage/profilepicture' . $user->profilepicture);

        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('profilepicture')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('profilepicture')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore =  time() . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $request->file('profilepicture')->storeAs('public/profilepicture', $fileNameToStore);

        $user->update([
            'profilepicture' => $fileNameToStore
        ]);
        
    }

    $user->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'birth_date' => $request->birth_date,
        'section' => $request->section,
        'unit' => $request->unit,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
    ]);

    return back()->withSuccess('You have successfully update User.');
}
```

i already tried

```
Storage::delete('/public/storage/profilepicture/' . $user->profilepicture);
Storage::delete('/storage/profilepicture/' . $user->profilepicture);
Storage::delete('profilepicture/' . $user->profilepicture);
```

but none of them is working. Or there is any other correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class Filesystem instead of Storage, and give it an absolute path like this:

```
// Declare    
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
    
// Using
$file = 'icon-256x256.png';
$path = public_path('profilepicture/' . $file);
Filesystem::delete($path);
```

You will delete the file successful!